# want to select same product_id but bigger id row

Tags: sql

i have some problem about sql , i want to select the bigger warehouse_product_id and with same product_id row,i have try to use

please help

Table:

http://postimg.org/image/mkavxnmg9/

i want to:

http://postimg.org/image/8msomu47l/

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a greatest-n-per-group solution. For a given `product_id` and `warehouse_id` pair you need to get the max `warehouse_product_id`:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM aTable t1
JOIN (
  SELECT product_id, warehouse_id, MAX(warehouse_product_id) maxVal
  FROM aTable
  GROUP BY product_id, warehouse_id
) t2
ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND t1.warehouse_id = t2.warehouse_id AND t1.warehouse_product_id = t2.maxVal
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM aTable t1
LEFT JOIN aTable t2
ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND t1.warehouse_id = t2.warehouse_id AND t1.warehouse_product_id < t2.warehouse_product_id
WHERE t2.warehouse_product_id IS NULL
```

These solutions should work on most DBMS.

Comment: Thanks,exactly what i want

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT warehouse_product_id FROM [your table] where product_id="value"
```

unless I missed what you're getting at, which is entirely possible

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed qty and enable have the same values for the same warehouse/product. If not, you'll need to join back to the table to get those.

```
select warehouse_id, max(warehouse_product_id) as item_id, product_id, max(qty), max(enable)
from warehouse_product
group by warehouse_id, product_id
```